# Trouble boolean joining objects. Blender export perceived as separate objects.

Tags: modifiers, objects, export, 3d-printing

I'm working on a ring I am willing to print out. I've sent my stl export to the printing place, but they claim that mesh I've sent consists of 3 separate objects. But when I'm working on blender, everything appears to be one solid object. 
The ring was created from 3 loops joined by boolean union modifier.
[image]

This is how other software sees my file
[image]

Does anyone know how else can I join it ?

Comment: Select it, go into edit mode, press P (Separate) and choose *By Loose Parts*. If the geometry isn't connected it will separate into different objects. You can try the boolean modifier again with the other alogrithm. Try offsetting the offsets by a tiny unnoticable value first..

Comment: They did separate. Did boolean with different solver (carve instead if Bmesh) and it worked ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Writing up the solution as a proper answer would be helpful if anyone else has this problem.